# Conda install does not install meta.yaml dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have defined a meta.yaml which I use for `conda build .`. The build works and I get my tar.gz2 file. However, when I try to install it, either using conda install --use-local xyz or conda install xyz...tar.gz2 in a fresh environment with only python installed, I only get:

```
conda install /Users/.../Downloads/xyz.tar.bz2

Downloading and Extracting Packages


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

when I then try to execute it, it says imports are missing. Those imports are defined in my meta.yaml run requirements:

```
package:
  name: xyz
  version: 1.0

source:
  path: .

build:
  channels:
    - bioconda
    - conda-forge

  noarch: python
  script: python -m pip install . --no-deps


run:
  channels:
    - bioconda
    - conda-forge

requirements:

  build:
    - python
    - pip
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - pandas
    - conda-forge::networkx
    - bioconda::ete3
    - biopython
    - numpy
    - lightgbm

about: ...
```

Am I missing something? Why is no site-package installed when I perform conda install? The packages index.json file contains the packages.

conda, conda-build are all up to date.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps purge your conda builds (`conda build purge`) and rebuild? the `--no-deps` in the `pip install` command makes me wonder... could you remove `--no-deps` and try again? btw is your username ?

Comment: yes, I tried purging and rebuilding already. Unfortunately the same result. I added the `--no-deps` because I do not want pip to install the dependencies but conda. When removing it, it might work, but only because pip is taking over. Please correct me if I got that wrong.
And yes, it is  ;)

Comment: yes, try without the `--no-deps`. recipes on conda-forge's feedstock usually use `script: {{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv`, so i would copy that . for example: https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/blob/5a23420b3a9ffe46a9cd75c766b0f62232d4f6d0/recipes/example/meta.yaml#L38

Comment: I tried it without the `--no-deps`, I get the same result.